# How to properly run an FFT on a windowed set of data from a pure sine wave

Tags: c#, fft, math.net

I am trying to experiment with Math.Net, specifically the FFT portion. I am attempting to extract the frequency domain information from a pure sine wave. Here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set up the wave and derive some useful info
            Double WaveFreq = 500;
            Double WavePeriod = 1 / WaveFreq;
            Double SampleFreq = 20000;
            Double SampleTime = (1 / SampleFreq);

            //Generate the wave using the above parameters
            var points = Generate.Sinusoidal(100000, SampleFreq, WaveFreq, 1);

            //Array to hold our complex numbers
            var data = new Complex[points.Length];

            //Set up the series to display our raw wave
            Series WaveSeries = new Series("Waveform");
            WaveSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

            //Creat the series for displaying the FFT
            Series FFTSeries = new Series("FFT Test");
            FFTSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

            //Populate both the wave series and the data array
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
            {
                Double x = SampleTime * i;
                WaveSeries.Points.AddXY(x, points[i]);
                data[i] = new Complex(x, points[i]);
            }

            //Create the window to evaluate (using a window 5 times wider than the wavelength of the lowest ferequency being measured)
            int WindowWidth = (int)Math.Round((1 / WaveFreq) / (1 / SampleFreq) * 5 + 0.5f);
            var HannWindow = Window.HannPeriodic(WindowWidth);
            var window = new Complex[WindowWidth];

            for(int i = 0; i < WindowWidth; i++)
            {
                var y = data[i].Imaginary * HannWindow[i];
                window[i] = new Complex(data[i].Real, y);
            }

            //Perform the FFT
            Fourier.Forward(window);

            //Add the calculated FFT to our FFTSeries
            foreach(Complex sample in window)
            {
                FFTSeries.Points.AddXY(sample.Phase, sample.Magnitude);
            }

            chart2.Series.Add(WaveSeries);
            chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = .01;
            chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -2;
            chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 2;

            chart1.Series.Add(FFTSeries);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1000;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 5;

        }
```

As you can see, I am generating a sine wave at a frequency of 500Hz, sampling at 20kHz and generating 10k Samples.

The output is as the following (FFT on the left, wave on the right)
[image]

The FFT shows absolutely nothing (asides from a peak of 1.8 around 0Hz)! I suspect it is probably an error with the windowing but for the life of me I can't see what it is.

Comment: When I try to replicate this I can't find the Window.HannPeriodic function. It is in the MathNet documentation, but I can only compile if I switch to just using Window.Hann. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KelsonBall It is in the 3.14.0-beta3 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some misunderstanding on complex numbers. In your code they seem to be used like points (x,y-tuples), but they have nothing to do with points at all. The complex equivalent of your real data points is an array where the real part of the complex numers match your real data points and the imaginary part is all zero. Essentially:

```
var window = new Complex[WindowWidth];
for (int i = 0; i < WindowWidth; i++)
{
    window[i] = new Complex(points[i] * HannWindow[i], 0.0);
}
```

If you need an easy way to get the correct x axis for your frequency plot, you can use the `FrequencyScale` function, along the lines of:

```
var scale = Fourier.FrequencyScale(WindowWidth, SampleFreq);
for (int i = 0; i < WindowWidth; i++)
{
    FFTSeries.Points.AddXY(scale[i], window[i].Magnitude);
}
```

You should see a spike at index 5, which according to the computed `scale` array corresponds to frequency 500, which matches with your wave frequency.

Note that the FFT routine returns the full spectrum including negative frequencies, so you should also see a spike of the same size at frequency -500.

Comment: Ahh thank you. I understand my error now. I was reading on `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx`, specifically where it says: "The real part of the complex number is positioned on the x-axis (the horizontal axis), and the imaginary part is positioned on the y-axis" So I assumed that you entered the point values, and then the `real` ad `imaginary` properties would calculate the complex equivalent.

Comment: As a quick follow up,  was reading about how one may need to "normalize" the FFT. Could this be the necessary step to bring the amplitudes in line with reality? Currently, the amplitudes seem to be dependent on where the frequency falls between 2 bins. I know that this is an effect of windowing, but I don't know how to correct for it. Do you have any resource available for this? Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: Maybe they refer to the FFT scaling? You can control this with the `FourierOptions` argument, but by default it already scales symmetrically, such that it satisfies parseval's theorem (time space energy = frequency space energy). This is different from e.g. MATLAB which scales asymmetrically and you'd have to scale yourself.

Comment: If you're interested in the energy of the spike, you can sum the squared magnitude of the spike sample and its close neighbour samples on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

The FFT is definitely there but the scale that you have mapped is wrong.

Just change the X axis and you will see it

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
```

It also seems like the sinusoidal wave form you generate is not right although I am no math net expert so I don't know. The center doesn't seem to be at zero.

Comment: Hey thanks! I thought that the y axis on the FFT chart would represent one to one the amplitude of the wave at that frequency. I see now that it doesn't. Can you explain how one should interpret the amplitude in the FFT graph? Thank you